# Java keytool easy way to add server cert from url/port

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a server with a self-signed certificate, but also requires client side cert authentication. I am having a rough time trying to get the raw CA server cert so I can import it into a keystore. Anyone have some suggestions on how to easily do that?

Answer (score 101):

Was looking at how to trust a certificate while using jenkins cli, and found
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12629 which has some recipe for that.

This will give you the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} </dev/null
```

if you are interested only in the certificate part, cut it out by piping it to:

```
| sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

and redirect to a file:

```
> ${HOST}.cert
```

Then import it using keytool:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias ${HOST} -file ${HOST}.cert \
    -keystore ${KEYSTOREFILE} -storepass ${KEYSTOREPASS}
```

In one go:

```
HOST=myhost.example.com
PORT=443
KEYSTOREFILE=dest_keystore
KEYSTOREPASS=changeme

# get the SSL certificate
openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} </dev/null \
    | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ${HOST}.cert

# create a keystore and import certificate
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts \
    -alias ${HOST} -file ${HOST}.cert \
    -keystore ${KEYSTOREFILE} -storepass ${KEYSTOREPASS}

# verify we've got it.
keytool -list -v -keystore ${KEYSTOREFILE} -storepass ${KEYSTOREPASS} -alias ${HOST}
```

Comment: Can I put HOST=*.example.com ?

Comment: For me, KEYSTOREPASS=changeit  not 'changeme'

Comment: Beginning with j7 in 2012, keytool (and CertificateFactory generally) ignores extraneous text in a PEM file for a cert, so you don't need the sed. Also with `-noprompt` _and_ `-storepass` you can pipe with no temp file: `openssl s_client -connect host:port | keytool -import -noprompt -alias nm -keystore file -storepass pw`

Answer (score 37):

I use openssl, but if you prefer not to, or are on a system (particularly Windows) that doesn't have it, **since java 7 in 2011 `keytool` can do the whole job**:

```
 keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port] -rfc >tempfile
 keytool -import [-noprompt] -alias nm -keystore file [-storepass pw] [-storetype ty] <tempfile 
 # or with noprompt and storepass (so nothing on stdin besides the cert) piping works:
 keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port] -rfc | keytool -import -noprompt -alias nm -keystore file -storepass pw [-storetype ty]
```

<strike>Conversely, for java 9 up always, and for earlier versions in many cases, Java can use a PKCS12 file for a keystore instead of the traditional JKS file, and</strike> **OpenSSL can create a PKCS12** without any assistance from keytool:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port </dev/null | openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys [-caname nm] [-passout option] -out p12file
# <NUL on Windows
# default is to prompt for password, but -passout supports several options 
# including actual value, envvar, or file; see the openssl(1ssl) man page
```

**BUT** (as I apparently hadn't yet found in 2018) this won't work as a truststore with 'standard' (Oracle/OpenJDK) Java crypto because that requires trusted cert(s) in a PKCS12 to have a special attribute OpenSSL doesn't know about. This *does* work if you install and use the BouncyCastle provider and specify the storetype which can affect (maybe break) other things, AND you specify 'friendly' name(s) with `-caname`. (corrected: `-caname` not `-name` or `nm`)

Comment: Nice to know, thanks! But it is a similar option than to install `keytool` :)

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I was looking for an option without using openssl and this did the trick beautifully :)

Comment: All other answers should redirect to this first. This is the concise way among others. Consider applying other answers in a container environment.

Answer (score 23):

There were a few ways I found to do this:

- Firefox: Add Exception -> Get Certificat -> View -> Details -> Export...
- KeyMan (http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/keyman) You can get SSL cert directly from the File -> Import menu
- InstallCert ([Code by Andreas Sterbenz](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java))

```
    java InstallCert [host]:[port] 
    keytool -exportcert -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file output.cert
    keytool -importcert -keystore [DESTINATION_KEYSTORE] -file output.cert
```

Comment: I've used Andreas Sterbenz's InstallCert class before too, its useful if you need a certificate for a host which doesn't accept HTTP GET requests

Comment: thanks wuntee, it helped me alot, because I got stock here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c :D ty

Answer (score 4):

You can export a certificate using Firefox, [this site](http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/Web-Browser-Firefox-Use-Certificate.html) has instructions.  Then you use [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) to add the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

Just expose [dnozay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733117/dnozay)'s answer to a function so that we can import multiple certificates at the same time.

Save it to a .sh file then run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

KEYSTORE_FILE=/path/to/keystore.jks
KEYSTORE_PASS=changeit


import_cert() {
  local HOST=$1
  local PORT=$2

  if [[ -z $PORT ]]; then
    PORT=443
  fi

  # get the SSL certificate
  openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ${HOST}.cert

  # delete the old alias and then import the new one
  keytool -delete -keystore ${KEYSTORE_FILE} -storepass ${KEYSTORE_PASS} -alias ${HOST} &> /dev/null

  # create a keystore (or update) and import certificate
  keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts \
      -alias ${HOST} -file ${HOST}.cert \
      -keystore ${KEYSTORE_FILE} -storepass ${KEYSTORE_PASS}

  # remove temp file
  rm ${HOST}.cert
}

# Change your sites here
import_cert stackoverflow.com 443
import_cert www.google.com # default port 443
import_cert 172.217.194.104 443 # google
```