# PKIX path building failed when running Teamprise-ant task

Tags: java, ant, tfs

I am having an xml which will connect to tfs through https connection to get latest files from it. I am trying to run this as ant task invoked from my java scheduler. When i try to invoke it I am getting the following error message :

**An error occurred: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

But if i invoke the ant task from a bat file directly, it is working fine without any issues.

Kindly help me out on how to handle the execption when invoking from java

Comment: The HTTPS address you are accessing uses has a self-signed SSL cert. Pretty common problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0):

These steps, based on [Oracle instructions](https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification), worked for me:

- Get [InstallCert.java](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) (the link in Oracle's instructions is broken)
- Compile and execute `java InstallCert [host]:[port]`

  - enter '1'
- Copy and rename the newly created jssecacerts file as %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts (backup the original, just in case)
- Rerun Ant, it should not complain about certificate anymore

There may be [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686042/1097104) as well.