# SSLHandshakeException using t3s weblogic

Tags: security, ssl, rmi, weblogic12c

I have done t3s setting and configured it. Now when I try to make a call getting below exception. Please help guys.

Have tried the url mentioned [steps Enterprise Software Development with Java: WebLogic Server SSL (https/t3s) and Java Web Start](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/06/weblogic-server-ssl-httpst3s-and-java.html)

As well as below code inclusion as per the [Configuring Transport-Level Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13713/transport.htm)

```
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification","true");  
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "weblogic.net");  
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.TrustKeyStore","CustomTrust");  
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName","TRUST_STORE_LOCATION");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase","TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType","JKS");
```

Exception :

```
[java] <Feb 25, 2014 1:14:22 AM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.>   
[java] <Feb 25, 2014 1:14:22 AM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>   
[java] <Feb 25, 2014 1:14:22 AM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090908> <Using the default WebLogic SSL Hostname Verifier implementation.>   
[java]   
[java] TYPE_PARAM = ERROR  
[java] CODE_PARAM = null  
[java] MESSAGE_PARAM = null  
[java]   
[java]  
[java] at junit.extensions.jfunc.SALQATestCase.runBare(SALQATestCase.java:111)  
[java] at junit.extensions.jfunc.SALQATestCase$1.protect(SALQATestCase.java:96)  
[java] at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)  
[java] at junit.extensions.jfunc.SALQATestCase.run(SALQATestCase.java:99)  
[java] at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)  
[java] at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)  
[java] at junit.extensions.jfunc.textui.SALQARunner.doRun(SALQARunner.java:69)  
[java] at junit.extensions.jfunc.textui.SALQARunner.run(SALQARunner.java:314)  
[java]  Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://xxxxxxxxxx.com:7002: Destination xx.xx.xx.xx, 7002 unreachable; nested exception is:   
[java] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination]  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:808)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:363)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:319)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)  
[java] at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)  
[java] at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)  
[java] at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)  
[java] at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)  
[java]  
[java] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3s://xxxxxxxxxx.com:7002: Destination xx.xx.xx.xx, 7002 unreachable; nested exception is:   
[java] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:169)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:342)  
[java] at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)  
[java] at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)  
[java] at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:337)  
[java] ... 21 more  
[java] Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination xx.xx.xx.xx, 7002 unreachable; nested exception is:   
[java] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:490)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:328)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:267)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:204)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)  
[java] at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
```

---

On netstat getting below list. I see 7002 on listen mode. Isn't it correct?

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep :7002
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:7002 :::*                        LISTEN      25657/java
tcp        0      0 ::xxxx:127.0.0.1:7002       :::*                        LISTEN      25657/java
tcp        0      0 xxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:7002 :::*                        LISTEN      25657/java
tcp        0      0 ::xxxx:xx.xxx.xx.xx:7002  :::*                        LISTEN      25657/java
```

Comment: It looks like Weblogic is throwing a completely inappropriate SSLHandshakeException when it should be throwing a ConnectException, but  what part of 'destination unreachable' don't you understand?

Answer (score 8):

SSL errors are often misleading.  An SSLHandshakeException is usually a certificate issue, (that the SSL connection cannot be validated as trusted).

Your server is likely signed with a *self-signed certificate*, which will usually need to be added to your cacerts keystore to allow SSL to trust it.  i.e., **You need to add the SSL Certificate from the Weblogic server to your JDK/JRE keystore.**  See the answer(s) to this question:

[How to properly import a selfsigned certificate into Java keystore that is available to all Java applications by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail)

If you are on UNIX, the commands at the link above work as-is.  If you are on windows, all of the UNIX utilities you need, (openssl, sed), are secretly included in the installation of GIT, or you can use cygwin.  All I had to do was to use openssl to grab the certificate and then use keytool, (part of the JDK), to add it to my JDK's cacerts file.  (%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts)

Note: If you import the certificate to your ~/.keystore, (on windows: %userprofile%.keystore), file it will still fail but you will likely get a different exception:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination`

Once you are successfully connected, it will look like this:

```
Connecting to t3s://*********:7001 with userid ********...
<Jul 23, 2014 4:00:25 PM EDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.>
<Jul 23, 2014 4:00:25 PM EDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
<Jul 23, 2014 4:00:25 PM EDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090908> <Using the default WebLogic SSL Hostname Verifier implementation.>
Successfully connected to Admin Server "AdminServer" that belongs to domain "******".
```

Another related post on retrieving and adding an SSL key (through java): [Java keytool easy way to add server cert from url/port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685548/java-keytool-easy-way-to-add-server-cert-from-url-port)

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is not a SSLHandshake error, it says

" java.net.ConnectException: t3s://xxxxxxxxxx.com:7002: Destination xx.xx.xx.xx, 7002 unreachable "

1) Check the url you are providing.

2) Do a telnet on that `DNS` port

3) Make sure there's no firewall blocking the request.

4) If 7002 if the port of your admin server (I am assuming you have only 1 server in domain) then try accessing `https://DNS:7002/console`  and see if that loads fine first.

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep :7002 is listing as LISTEN. Isn't it correct?

Comment: SSLHandshake error comes after a successful TCP connection. The error message is misleading. Despite the error, the port isn't unreachable - the port is reachable but then the SSL connection cannot be securely made.