# Disconnected TeamCity Build Agent after update TeamCity Server SSL certificate

Tags: java, https, teamcity

We use TeamCity 7.1.5., I updated TeamCity Server site certificate (replaced *server.p12* file with new one) for new time period and TeamCity Server lost connection with single Agent. Agent status is Disconnected, Authorized, Enabled. With WEB Browser I navigated to TeamCity site and made sure new certificate is valid.

Into *teamcity-agent.log* file I see many similar messages, for sample:

> [2014-03-20 16:37:11,694]   WARN -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Ping problem: Call https://example.com/RPC2 buildServer.ping: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How I can fix this Agent connectivity problem with new certificate?

With old site certificate TeamCity worked properly.

I see difference in Details of old and new certificate. Old Certificate Signature Algorithm  is PKCs #1  SHA-1  With RSA Encryption.  New Certificate Signature Algorithm  is PKCs #1  SHA-256  With RSA Encryption.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the same problem by adding the new cert to default truststore of java:

And import it into java default truststore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file <ca_file> -alias <CA_ALIAS> -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

- [tmpFile] - name of generated file.
- [servers-keystore] - configured keystore of your server
- [CA_ALIAS] - alias of the cert to identify in keystore
- [ca_file] - ca_file from webside (maybe get with chrome expor)

Check, that the $JAVA_HOME path is correct, maybe replace it with absolut path.
The default passwort for truststore (cacerts) is: changeit

For more information about java keytool: [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

**If you do not have the ca_file check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685548/java-keytool-easy-way-to-add-server-cert-from-url-port/3686042#3686042)**

For TeamCity agent installed under Windows, use "agent_installation_path/jre" as "JAVA_HOME". [Source](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server#UsingHTTPStoaccessTeamCityserver-JVMConfiguration)