# HTTPS connection not secure

Tags: java, ssl, https, keytool

I created a certificate for my Java application with Keytool, that generated a *keystore.jks*, *carets.jks*, and *server.cer*. I imported them inside *cacerts.jks* and I added the file *server.cer* also inside Google (Trusted root certificates authorities), but it's always a not secure connection.

I'm a bit confused that I should import the *server.cer* file in the client (here Google as client) like [this](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome) or download a certification from Google and import it into *cacerts.jks* like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465472/using-browsers-certificate-in-java-program) says. I already inserted there *server.cer* generated by Keytool inside Google Trusted root certificates authorities and it's always not secure.

Comment: You already installed the certificate for your own machine aswell?

Comment: yes I did it (in local computer and automatic..)

Comment: There can be several issues and you don't provide enough detail. Please put the exact error message you get (and don't provide here) and you'll likely find many hits regarding exactly this problem and also on stackoverflow.com. If this does not help please add the exact error message and all details about your certificate and the URL you access to your question so that one can narrow down your problem.

Comment: I don't have a problem with my code cause https://... is working but not secure my question is simple, I want my connection to be secure with the green lock so I should put the certificate from keytool (server.cer) into the client (example google Trusted root certificates authorities) or I download a certificate from the client and import it into my cacerts.jks

Comment: when I charged the keytool certification on the browser he display a message "connection not secure" (invalid certificate)