# Bamboo agent - error SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, bamboo

I want to install bamboo agent on my working computer. I have downloaded the jar file and try to run it with following syntax

```
java -jar atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-5.7.0.jar https://bamboo.xxxxx.org/agentServer/
```

I got error **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated**.

The source of this error is clear to me - we have a self-signed SSL sertificate. I tried to run with following parameters

```
java -Dbamboo.agent.ignoreServerCertName=true -jar atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-5.7.0.jar https://bamboo.xxxxx.org/agentServer/
```

but it does not work as well.

I tried to add the certificate using this link [Java keytool easy way to add server cert from url/port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685548/java-keytool-easy-way-to-add-server-cert-from-url-port)

The sertificate seems to be installed, but it does not help. I still have the following error.

Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that bamboo did not obtained (for some reason) the keystorage created by keytool.

I needed to manually set the keystore in the bamboo configuration. In config/wrapper.conf you need to add following lines

```
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/#MODIFY_ME_TO_MY_HOME#/bamboo-agent-home/keystores/client.ks
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=#MY_AWESOME_PASSWORD#
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/#MODIFY_ME_TO_MY_HOME#/bamboo-agent-home/keystores/client.ts
```

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you (fyi) - which i'm assuming it did because its yours

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if you are running Bamboo behind Apache with SSL, if your default SSL VirtualHost is not returning the same SSLCertificate as your Bamboo VirtualHost. We had a similar problem, because I didn't know /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf created a VirtualHost.